# Moved to macports and having issues with database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, macports, mysql5

I moved to macports and trying to run rake db:migrate, but getting

```
$ rake db:migrate(in /Users/me/work/myproject)
rake aborted!
Mysql::Error: Table 'myproject_development.users' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`
```

I think it might be my database.yml?  What do I need to change since I am now using macports and mysql5.  Prior to this the only thing I did was use CocoaMySql to create my db myproject_development.

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: myproject_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: myproject_test
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock

production:
  adapter: mysql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: myproject_production
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

//////// results of rake db:migrate --trace //////////////

```
                rake db:migrate --trace
            (in /Users/me/work/myproject)
            ** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
            ** Invoke environment (first_time)
            ** Execute environment
            rake aborted!
            Mysql::Error: Table 'myproject_development.users' doesn't exist: SHOW FIELDS FROM `users`
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:219:in `log'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:323:in `execute'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:469:in `columns'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1271:in `columns'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1284:in `column_names'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.5.4/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/ordering.rb:33:in `ordering_condition_details'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.5.4/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/ordering.rb:25:in `create_condition'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.5.4/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/or_conditions.rb:28:in `create_condition'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/searchlogic-2.5.4/lib/searchlogic/named_scopes/column_conditions.rb:63:in `respond_to?'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:1481:in `respond_to?'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/observer.rb:183:in `flatten'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/observer.rb:183:in `observed_classes'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/observer.rb:166:in `initialize'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/singleton.rb:94:in `new'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/singleton.rb:94:in `instance'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/observer.rb:38:in `instantiate_observers'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/observer.rb:36:in `each'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/observer.rb:36:in `instantiate_observers'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:15:in `define_dispatcher_callbacks'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:182:in `call'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:182:in `evaluate_method'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `each'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `send'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:276:in `run_callbacks'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:51:in `send'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:51:in `run_prepare_callbacks'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:631:in `prepare_dispatcher'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:185:in `process'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
            /Users/me/work/myproject/config/environment.rb:14
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
            /Users/me/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:607:in `invoke_prerequisites'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `each'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:604:in `invoke_prerequisites'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:596:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
            /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
            /opt/local/bin/rake:19:in `load'
            /opt/local/bin/rake:19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app can't find the mysql table.

Basically it means a few things:

1. Are you connecting to the correct database?
2. Is your database up to date?
3. Do you have the correct credentials to access the db?
4. Do you have the correct gem?
5. Since it is mysql, are you connecting to the correct socket?

check all of these and you'll probably find out what was wrong with your db. Some additional pointers:

1. Are you sure your migrations are correct and in order? (You're not selecting from a table not yet created, are you?)

Comment: I am creating the database then running rake db:migrate on it so I have no other db.
I can't update the db until its created
root 
gems mysql 2.8.1  on mysql5 so not sure
socket is  linked resource tmp/mysql.sock
added database.yml above

Comment: can you also do a rake db:migrate --trace? its probable that your migration is not in order? (e.g. you have an rename_column on a table that doesn't exist yet)

Comment: For some reason the first 4 migrations are 
001_blah
002_blaadfs
003_blahblah
004_blakdd
20100222171241_create_notices.rb
.....
In this case how would rake run these or what order?

Comment: yeah that's not gonna work. you'll have to fix your migrations one by one. it's a pain but you'll only have to blame yourself or anyone who did those migrations :P

Comment: How do I fix them? rename the migrations ?

Comment: what's in the first four? random stuff or are there code in them? if it's just random stuff just take those 4 out

Answer (score 0):

Have you done `rake db:create:all` ?